# Installing Ubuntu Server on Network Switch

Tags: server, wifi-hardware-switch

This might be a little unusual.

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server on a Network Switch (AS5710-54X ).

This switch comes with ONIE (http://www.onie.org), which is " an open source initiative that defines an open “install environment” for bare metal network switches. ONIE enables a bare metal network switch ecosystem where end users have a choice among different network operating systems. "

Now I have installed other NOS such as ONL(http://opennetlinux.org/docs/deploy) on the switch, where it comes with an installer (which is nothing but a shell script which installs the network operating system)

I was wondering if there is a method of installing Ubuntu Server on the switch using an installer like I mentioned above, other than having a bootable pendrive or a cd.

Comment: Would Ubuntu even support handling the switch in the first place? The switch has limited storage and memory.

Comment: hey @Zacharee1 . Assume that there is sufficient place. How do I go about it?

Comment: I don't think you can. Ubuntu needs BIOS or EFI to boot, which I don't think the switch has. Also, the installer isn't automatic.

Comment: @Zacharee1 the switch has ONIE, which helps to boot.